# Python-based API with WSDL generator

Tags: python, web-services

I do not have much experience in building web service, the one I am aware of is using Java with Apache axis, where we have tool like java2wsdl to compile written codes a WSDL file, but using Python as the programming language to build the web service, is there any possibility to compile written code to WSDL?

I have heard of a few frameworks for building Python-based web service, such as

- flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/
- soaplib: https://github.com/soaplib/soaplib
- django-piston: https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home

soaplib seems like to have the ability to generate WSDL, but I think there are many more besides what listed above. Which frameworks are really relevant and suitable (with sufficient documentations for newbies) to build a Python-based web service?
Your feedback is highly appreciated.